# How to wire up virtual-hyperscript, hyperscript-helpers, and main-loop

Tags: virtual-dom, hyperscript

I'm looking at an [example by substack](https://github.com/substack/training/blob/master/web-dev-whirlwind/example/dom/hyperx-vdom/main.js) of using hyperscript, main-loop, and hyperx.

I'd like to recreate this example using [hyperscript-helpers](https://github.com/ohanhi/hyperscript-helpers) to get code similar to Elm. That module says it supports both `hyperscript` and `virtual-hyperscript`, so I'm trying `virtual-hyperscript`.

My code looks like this:

```js
var vdom = require('virtual-dom')
var vh = require('virtual-hyperscript');
var hh = require('hyperscript-helpers')(vh);
var main = require('main-loop')

var div  = hh.div;
var span = hh.span;
var h1   = hh.h1;

var loop = main({ times: 0 }, render, vdom)
document.querySelector('#content').appendChild(loop.target)

function render(state) {
  return h1('title');
}
```

And it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

What's going wrong? I assume something's not wired up correctly because

```
console.log(loop.target) //null
```

If it helps, I can post my html and the browserify build command I'm using

Comment: This works if I change line 2 to `var vh = require('virtual-dom/h');`, but I'd love to understand why :)

Comment: Is `#content` just a div? Do post your html please :)

Comment: @danpaz https://github.com/JuanCaicedo/elm-to-js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`virtual-hyperscript` is moved to https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/tree/master/virtual-hyperscript

See README at https://github.com/Raynos/virtual-hyperscript

The `virtual-dom/h` is just a new version of `virtual-hyperscript`.

Comment: Ah I see! The solution is then to make a PR to hyperscript-helpers updating their documentation. Thanks!